# JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object

Tags: c#, serialization, json.net, httpclient, webclient

i am very new to C# and Visualstudio2017 and have been stuck on this for literally weeks. Searching the net but not finding results relating to this that i can understand properly. What i am trying to do is get json data from 
https://zkillboard.com/api/stats/characterID/224802743/ 
then convert it into usable data that i can get and display certain data in certain textboxes. I used https://quicktype.io/ to convert the json into C# array.

**MainForm.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Net;
using ZKILLBOARDDATA;



namespace MainProgram
{

    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DoubleBuffered = true;
            this.SetStyle(ControlStyles.ResizeRedraw, true);

        }


        public async void Btn_submit_ClickAsync(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             var remoteUri = "https://zkillboard.com/api/stats/characterID/224802743/";
             var myWebClient = new WebClient();
             myWebClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "C# App testing");
             var jsonString = await myWebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(remoteUri);
             var data = GettingStarted.FromJson(jsonString);
        }   
    }
}
```

**Zkill.cs**

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;
// To parse this JSON data, add NuGet 'Newtonsoft.Json' then do:
//
//    using ZKILLBOARDDATA;
//
//    var data = GettingStarted.FromJson(jsonString);
//
namespace ZKILLBOARDDATA
{

    public partial class GettingStarted
    {
        [JsonProperty("attackers")]
        public Attacker[] Attackers { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("killmail_id")]
        public long KillmailId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("killmail_time")]
        public string KillmailTime { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("moon_id")]
        public long? MoonId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("solar_system_id")]
        public long SolarSystemId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("victim")]
        public Victim Victim { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("war_id")]
        public long? WarId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("zkb")]
        public Zkb Zkb { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Zkb
    {
        [JsonProperty("awox")]
        public bool Awox { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("fittedValue")]
        public double FittedValue { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hash")]
        public string Hash { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("locationID")]
        public long LocationID { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("npc")]
        public bool Npc { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("points")]
        public long Points { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("solo")]
        public bool Solo { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("totalValue")]
        public double TotalValue { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Victim
    {
        [JsonProperty("alliance_id")]
        public long? AllianceId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("character_id")]
        public long? CharacterId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("corporation_id")]
        public long CorporationId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("damage_taken")]
        public long DamageTaken { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public Item[] Items { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("position")]
        public Position Position { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ship_type_id")]
        public long ShipTypeId { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Position
    {
        [JsonProperty("x")]
        public double X { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("y")]
        public double Y { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("z")]
        public double Z { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Item
    {
        [JsonProperty("flag")]
        public long Flag { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("item_type_id")]
        public long ItemTypeId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("items")]
        public Item[] Items { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("quantity_destroyed")]
        public long? QuantityDestroyed { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("quantity_dropped")]
        public long? QuantityDropped { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("singleton")]
        public long Singleton { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class Attacker
    {
        [JsonProperty("alliance_id")]
        public long? AllianceId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("character_id")]
        public long? CharacterId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("corporation_id")]
        public long? CorporationId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("damage_done")]
        public long DamageDone { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("faction_id")]
        public long? FactionId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("final_blow")]
        public bool FinalBlow { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("security_status")]
        public double SecurityStatus { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("ship_type_id")]
        public long? ShipTypeId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("weapon_type_id")]
        public long? WeaponTypeId { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class GettingStarted
    {
        public static GettingStarted[] FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GettingStarted[]>(json, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this GettingStarted[] self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        };
    }
}
```

Here is the error message i am getting from VS2017.

> JsonSerializationException: Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'ZKILLBOARDDATA.GettingStarted[]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.
>
> Path 'allTimeSum', line 1, position 14.

Comment: I feel like the error message gives you as good of an answer as you can get, given the information you’ve provided.  Your JSON source apparently is not an array.

Comment: What do i need to do to get this working. I have tried using c# inbuilt paste special which doesnt work. Im lost.

Comment: The web request returns a JSON **object** (starting with **{**) but your deserialization call expected a JSON **array** (starting with **[**) (the exception message is very clear). Seems you want to cherrypick some data from the returned JSON, but your code has not enough magic powder to complete that task

Comment: I just checked the JSON response from the link, and **none** of the GettingStarted properties can be found at any position in that response.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
     var remoteUri = "https://zkillboard.com/api/stats/characterID/224802743/";
     var myWebClient = new WebClient();
     myWebClient.Headers.Add("user-agent", "C# App testing");
     myWebClient.Headers.Add("content-type", "application/json");

     var jsonString = myWebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync(remoteUri).Result;

     var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonString);
     //OR
     var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<YourModel>(jsonString);
```

I don't think you need this in your model

```
public partial class GettingStarted
    {
        public static GettingStarted[] FromJson(string json) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<GettingStarted[]>(json, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public static class Serialize
    {
        public static string ToJson(this GettingStarted[] self) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(self, Converter.Settings);
    }

    public class Converter
    {
        public static readonly JsonSerializerSettings Settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            MetadataPropertyHandling = MetadataPropertyHandling.Ignore,
            DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None,
        };
    }
```

Comment: You can use the data like obj.someProperty and set it in the text area. For ex : textbox1.setText or textbox1.innerHtml = obj.someProeprty;

Comment: that  code you recommended i remove was generated by https://quicktype.io 
and so was the classes and jsonobjects.
i left it in my code and replaced the code you asked me to try and i am not getting that error anymore, but i am now getting. (this method lacks 'await' operators and will run synchronously.)
however how do i go about putting certain data that i received into certain textboxes etc.

Comment: it is a windows form application not WPF btw. 
innerHtml not reconized. neither is setText. i have also tried 
OutputBox.Text = obj.Zkb.Points;  (but its returning error, Cannot implicitly convert type 'long' to 'string')

Comment: I didn't know what you were using so I just gave you the normal advice how you could set text in textfield. You are missing the basic things. You could set value like OutputBox.Text = obj.Zkb.Points.toString().

Comment: https://github.com/kovacev/EVE-LOCAL-SCAN


i put it on Github so u can try it out. i just cant seem to get it to work properly

Comment: @DANNYKOVACEV Use the debugger, put a breakpoint at [this line](https://github.com/kovacev/EVE-LOCAL-SCAN/blob/master/MainProgram/MainForm.cs#L51) and check the property values from *obj*. Every property will have the default value (zero or null). If you want to know why, check my comments below your question

Comment: @DANNYKOVACEV Your created model is not okay. When you dynamic deserialize the object you get different object kind of like object within the object. Try this website http://json2csharp.com/# and you will get a new model. In your github you are trying to find obj.Attacker which is not available in the JSON at all. This question is going beyond the scope as well.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem; I solved it by using the new default `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize` instead of the `Newtonsoft`'s

```
using System.Text.Json;    
var obj = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<YourMODEL>(jsonStr);
```

p.s. https://quicktype.io is great (although seems somewhat outdated for C#); I've also tried http://json2csharp.com but my json file is big and it froze up.

Also sometimes (in particularly for deeply nested complex json) quicktype doesn't add the list/array type; e.g. `MyObj` instead of `List<MyObj>`.
Sometimes it is possible to "fix" it by picking T[] first and then List from the website's generation menu option `Use T[] or List<T>`.